# Exclude iOS devices from Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to exclude iOS devices from appearing in Firebase analytics?

I don't want mine or my team's usage to appear in them.

Comment: In code you could do it like this: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#disable_collection_on_ios.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Would be nice to have a permanent feature where you can add all of your teams devices. Every company's data is slightly skewed because of this and it is particularly worse for startups (smaller user base). I'm surprised this isn't a feature.

Comment: Sounds valid, but for now the above is all I could fine. I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks frank. I have filed a feature request. Would be amazing to have this.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable analytics data collection in your AppDelegate.

```
AnalyticsConfiguration.shared().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
```

You can also enable collection at any point in the by calling the method again. IF you want to permanently disable data collection just set the **FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED** flag in your Info.plist to **YES**.